# Django FileField wont update path and url after save()

Tags: python, django

I have this model:

```
class Galeria(models.Model):
    galeriaid = models.AutoField(db_column='GaleriaID', primary_key=True)   
    nombre = models.CharField(db_column='Nombre', max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)   
    ruta = models.FileField(db_column='Ruta', max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
```

And I overrided the **save()** to make my file look like **{pk}.jpg** or **{pk}.mp4**. The code works but it doesnt update the file.path and file.url. I get "media/{file}" instead of "media/imagenes/%Y%m/{file}". What am I doing wrong, the save() code below:

```
def save( self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
        # Call save for post id
        super( Galeria, self ).save( *args, **kwargs )

        ruta = self.ruta
        if ruta:
            # Create new file using pk and ext file
            oldfile = self.ruta.name
            dot = oldfile.rfind( '.' )
            newfile = str( self.pk ) + oldfile[dot:]

            # Create new file and remove the old one
            if newfile != oldfile:
                self.ruta.storage.delete( newfile )
                if newfile.endswith(".jpg"):
                    self.ruta.storage.save( "imagenes/" + str(timezone.now().strftime("%Y/%m/")) + str(newfile), ruta )
                elif newfile.endswith(".mp4"):
                    self.ruta.storage.save( "videos/" + str(timezone.now().strftime("%Y/%m/")) + str(newfile), ruta )
                else:
                    self.ruta.storage.save( newfile, ruta )
                self.ruta.name = newfile 
                self.ruta.close()
                self.ruta.storage.delete( oldfile )

        # keep the changes
        super( Galeria, self ).save( *args, **kwargs )
```

I tried adding a function to upload to, but still doesnt work.

Comment: You should just use the `FieldFile`'s `save()` method, you don't need to use its storage, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.save). For example `self.ruta.save(new_name, self.ruta.file)`

Comment: I solved the problem, but it's good to know the use of FieldFile, I will try to implement that, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed to this

```
        if newfile != oldfile:
            self.ruta.storage.delete( newfile )                
            if newfile.endswith(".jpg"):
                print("Termina como jpg if")
                self.ruta.storage.save( "imagenes/" + str(timezone.now().strftime("%Y/%m/")) + str(newfile), ruta )
                self.ruta.name = "imagenes/" + str(timezone.now().strftime("%Y/%m/")) + str(newfile)
            elif newfile.endswith(".mp4"):
                print("Termina como mp4 if")
                self.ruta.storage.save( "videos/" + str(timezone.now().strftime("%Y/%m/")) + str(newfile), ruta )
                self.ruta.name = "videos/" + str(timezone.now().strftime("%Y/%m/")) + str(newfile)
            else:
                self.ruta.storage.save( newfile, ruta )
                self.ruta.name = newfile 
            self.ruta.close()
            self.ruta.storage.delete( oldfile )
```